# Configuration and inheritance chains in PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, configuration

I have a few standard classes:

```
abstract class Parent {}
class Child1 extends Parent {}
class Child2 extends Parent {}
```

The `Parent` class contains logic common to both child classes, but each child class has its own additional logic.

For each of my clients, this logic can be configurable.  So for any particular client, I may have:

```
abstract class ClientParent {}
class ClientChild1 extends ClientParent {}
class ClientChild2 extends ClientParent {}
```

The problem I'm having is how to get the logic from the standard classes into these ones.  The first approach would be something like this:

```
abstract class ClientParent extends Parent {}
```

Okay, now I have the standard parent logic in all my client-specific classes.  Great.  But the child classes are already extending `ClientParent`, so we can't do the same thing for them.  My "solution" is then to do this:

```
abstract class Parent {}
class Child1 extends ClientParent {}
class Child2 extends ClientParent {}

abstract class ClientParent extends Parent {}
class ClientChild1 extends Child1 {}
class ClientChild2 extends Child2 {}
```

There; now all the appropriate logic is passed down and everybody's happy.  Except that now my standard classes are *coupled to a particular client*.  As I have many clients, this is obviously no good.

What's my out here?  Is there a way to address this through inheritance alone, or should I look into more complex configuration injection strategies?

**Edit:**

I'm using PHP 5.3, so I am unable to use [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not support multiple inheritance which is what I think you are trying to approximate here. It does however support (as of 5.4) [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), which in many cases can provide you with comparable functionality.

```
trait ParentTrait {
   public function someUsefulMethod(){/*...*/};
   public function someOtherUsefulMethod(){/*...*/};
}

abstract class ClientParent(){}

class ClientChild1 extends ClientParent {
      use ParentTrait;
}

$clientChild1 = new ClientChild1();
$clientChild1->someUsefulMethod();
```

Another option would be to use composition instead, possibly for your problem employing the Strategy pattern would work.

```
class SuperWidget extends Widget{
    private $dataStrategy;

    public function __construct(DataStrategy $strategy){
         $this->dataStrategy = $strategy;
    }

    // do this if you need to expose the functionality. 
    public function getData(){
        return $this->dataStrategy->getData();
    }

    // or if you are just using it in your class
    public function renderWidget($option){
        $data = $this->dataStrategy->getData($option);
        // use the data to render the widget;
        return $renderedWidget;
    }
}

$dataStrategy = JsonDataStrategy("http://data.source.url/jsonService.php");
$widget = new SuperWidget($dataStrategy);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to use traits (I'll add this to my question).  It's not really multiple inheritance per se; I'm really just trying to figure out how to propagate configuration in a DRY way.  Obviously I'm initially trying to use inheritance to do it, but I'm open to anything.

Comment: I gave a +1, as this answer would certainly help those with a similar problem who are using PHP 5.4+.

Comment: @drrcknisn What is the relationship between an instance of your ClientChild1 class and an instance of Parent class. I believe there is a way through this using composition but how abstract the class names are on the example code makes it difficult to determine what the best way to compose the objects is. In your case would the statement "a ClientClass1 is a Parent" make sense or is "a ClientClass1 needs a parent" make more sense.

Comment: "ClientChild1 is a Parent" makes sense, but since all these classes are just containers of widgets (some of which need to be inherited), they don't *have* to be in the same inheritance tree.  I think composition might work, but I've yet to wrap my head around how to keep it DRY if I do it that way.

Comment: Just wrap the functionality that should be shared in a different object and pass it into the object... I will add an example to the answer.